# IdentityServer4 response_mode web_message

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am trying to implement IdentityServer4 on .NET Core 3.1, and I have stucked on

```
/authorize?response_mode=web_message&...
```

as defined in [OAuth 2.0 Web Message Response Mode specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-sakimura-oauth-wmrm-00). It is particularly useful when using Silent Authentication.

Has anyone implemented web_message response mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that this `response_mode` is supported by IdentityServer4? It's not part of the OIDC spec as far as I know but it may be possible to implement it yourself.

For client side apps OIDC already supports silent authentication. The client uses a hidden iframe to make the `authorize` call and the callback endpoint itself uses the `postMessage` API to pass the result to the client application. The `oidc-client-js` library implements this out of the box.

For serverside applications the typical approach is to use a refresh token to automatically renew the access token as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I did read doc - https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html - but sadly there is no mention about web_message